# Calculate Triangle Area: Can a Python function find the area with base and height?

Tags: python, list, function

Write a function `triangle_area(base, height)` that takes the base and height of a triangle as input and returns the area of the triangle.

this is the code I wrote in py

```
def triangle_area(base, height):

area = (base*height) / 2
in1 = int(area)
flo1 = float(area)

i = 0
x = 0
s = str(area)

while i < len(s):
    if (s[i]) == ".":
        x += 1
        i += 1
    else:
        i += 1
   
if x > 0:
    print(in1)
elif x == 0:
    print(flo1)
```

it is supposed to output an int when there is no remainder (like 31), and when it isn't a perfect whole number, it is supposed to output a float (like 31.5)

the problem is that when i run the code, it always outputs an int, and not a float, like if the numbers are 7 and 9, it is supposed to output 31.5, but instead it outputs 31, so why is this?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: should be python3

Comment: Indentation is wrong.  Don't know if that's a SO rendering issue or a problem in your code.

Comment: if indentation is wrong then why is it stil printing?

Comment: @Aqua the indentation of the code in this question is definitely wrong, and would raise a `SyntaxError` fi you tried to run it. You need to indent the function body

Comment: I ran it without the function (just the body of the code by itself), and i was able to print and output, but the output was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in float method `is_integer()`:

```py
def triangle_area(base, height):
    area = (base * height) / 2
    return int(area) if area.is_integer() else area
```